# In Powershell how can I pass an array as an argument, which is one of multiple arguments to Start-Process -ArgumentList

Tags: powershell

ScriptToInvoke.ps1:

```
[CmdletBinding()]
param (
    [Parameter(Mandatory=$True)]
    [string[]]$StringArray,
    [ValidateSet('Mode1', 'Mode2', 'Mode3')]
    [string]$Mode = 'Mode1'
)

$count = $StringArray.Count
Write-Verbose ("String array count ($count): $StringArray")
```

ScriptCallingStartProcess.ps1:

```
$stringArray = @('String1','String2','String3')
Start-Process powershell -Verb RunAs
-ArgumentList "-NoExit -File ScriptToInvoke.ps1 -StringArray ""$stringArray"" -Mode Mode3 -Verbose"
```

In this case the `$stringArray` is treated as an array containing one element:

[screen capture of script run output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wM2XX.png)

I have tried multiple variations passing the `$stringArray` argument:

`-StringArray $stringArray`

`-StringArray @($stringArray)`

`-StringArray @(,@($stringArray))`

each with the same error:
*A positional parameter cannot be found that accepts argument 'String2'*

As I understand it the double quotes around the ArgumentList value result in any variable being parsed.  Is it possible to prevent this from happening?  Or is there an alternative approach?

My use case involves attempting to re-run the Powershell script with elevated permissions to uninstall a Windows update, which is why I use `Start-Process` with `-Verb RunAs`.

Comment: The problem is that the command line for starting a new process won't deliver an array. It will be a string. My suggestion would be to restructure the script you're invoking.

Comment: Thanks Bill, I might go with having multiple parameters that default to an empty string in that case.  I don't expect to need more than a few to cater for the number of strings I expect in the array.

Comment: One possible alternative is to provide a comma-delimited string to `ScriptToInvoke.ps1` and use `-split` to get an array from it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's one way. `ScriptCallingStartProcess.ps1`:

```
$stringArray = @('String1','String2','String3')
$OFS=","
Start-Process powershell.exe -Verb Runas "-NoExit -File \ScriptToInvoke.ps1 $stringArray -Mode Mode3 -Verbose"
```

`ScriptToInvoke.ps1`:

```
[CmdletBinding()]
param (
  [Parameter(Mandatory=$True)]
  [String] $InputData,
  [ValidateSet('Mode1', 'Mode2', 'Mode3')]
  [string]$Mode = 'Mode1'
)

$StringArray = $InputData -split ','
$count = $StringArray.Count
Write-Verbose ("String array count ($count): $StringArray")
```

(that is, pass a comma-delimited string as first parameter, then split inside second script)

Answer (score 0):

I escaped the double quotes, and it seems to work ok:

```
Start-Process powershell -Verb RunAs -ArgumentList "-NoExit -File test.ps1 -StringArray `"$stringArray`" -Mode Mode3 -Verbose"
```

Comment: Nice try, but that passes a string to the `-StringArray` parameter, not an array (take a careful look at the output of `ScriptToInvoke.ps1`).

Comment: Yeah the count will be reported as 1